# Firewall causes Titanium web proxy to fail to change request url

Tags: c#, reverse-proxy, titanium-web-proxy

When trying to change the request URL on an Https request to a site that is blocked by a firewall(example.com in this example), the request gets an error

"Error occured whilst handling session request: Could not establish connection to www.example.com".

I had thought that it was the ClientHelloInfo that was causing the problem but even if I set it to clear with `e.HttpClient.ConnectRequest.ClientHelloInfo.Extensions.Clear()` it still fails.

Also, if trying to do the same thing with an Http request it works.

The code that changes the url request.

```
e.HttpClient.Request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://someotheresite.com");
e.HttpClient.Request.Host = new Uri("https://someotheresite.com").Host;
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: It is the clienthello causing it, is there anyway to stop it from sending or forward it to another place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been fixed. You must update titanium proxy to Titanium.Web.Proxy.3.0.892-beta.

https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy/issues/543